# Upsert using deltalake python (not spark)

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I have a deltetable on s3 and now I am trying to use deltalake python package to upsert data based on the primary key (bunch of small files every x mins using spark every time too expensive).  Currently I don't see a way to do it from python (not spark).  Is there a way?
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/merge.html#language-python (just in python vs pyspark)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no API for that using the `delta-rs` implementation (the `deltalake` package is just a Python binding for the Rust implementation).

There is an [issue](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/752) which requests this functionality already, but I don't know whether this is being worked on.

Comment: I think [this ticket](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/850) is more comprehensive and up to date (linked form the other one). Looks like as of 2023 July there's a merge implementation that loads the whole table in memory and overwrites it, and there's ongoing discussion of efficiency improvements in 2023 Sep.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the feature is worked on since there is an recent, active pull request https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/pull/1685